# Why do I get very different results for SVG path i.e. vs chrome?

Tags: svg

Hi I have this SVG path and it works perfectly in IE (oddly) but only displays a tiny line in Chrome. Any help appreciated!

```
<svg class="svgs" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path style="stroke:#ff0000; fill:none;" d="M428 237L200 500"/></svg>
```

style:

```
    .svg {
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not specified a height or width (or a viewBox).

The default canvas size is 300 x 150px and you're mostly drawing outside of that.

Looks like Chrome (and Firefox) default to overflow: hidden; whereas IE defaults to overflow: visible

Best specify a size and restrict your drawing to that size.

Comment: wow thanks overflow: visible did work!. I'll now look into the viewBox and/or height width

Comment: overflow: visible is a bad idea performance wise. If you need it, it indicates you've done something wrong.

Comment: ok thanks so if i use viewBox (or height and width), can other DOM elements still be visible within that same area?

Comment: sure, but viewBox is about the internal units of what you're drawing. width and height is about how big the canvas area is.

Comment: thanks so  for anyone else in this mess, height and width without setting overflow also solved my issue